# CENTER_CROP ImageScaleType scaling ratio

Tags: android, image, scaletype

Here is what the official documentation for center_crop is:

> CENTER_CROP : Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect
>   ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be
>   equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus
>   padding).

What i don't understand is how saying "equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view(minus padding)" is justified. For a image of arbitrary dimensions, how can i predict what the rendered image will look like?
So, given a image, if they say scaling will be such that dimansions will be equal to or larger than, how can i say what ratio will be used to scale the image. Can someone tell me just how 'larger than' can be predicted?

Does the scaling ratio depend upon the size of the image??

Answer (score 1):

The image will be scaled PROPORTIONALLY to fill the whole place which you set with height and width. When both height and width will be reached, the parts of the image which are larger than a corresponding size (the height or the width), will be cut off. So, if the width will be larger, then the image will be cut off from the left and the right sides. The image will be cut off only in one direction - only horizontally, or only vertically.

Comment: suppose my image is of dimension 200x50 and the imageView is 50x50, what part of the image wil be seen?

Comment: Ya but considering the aspect ratio of the image being maintained, Exactly which pixels will be visible and is white padding added at any of the sides?

Comment: If the width is 200 and the height is 50 (I guess so), the 1-75 (by X axis) will be cut off, the 76-125 will be visible, the 126-200 will be cut off. There will be no padding, if you'll not set it.

Comment: Any guess about height and width would have been fine ;-) .Thanks alot